# WPF Remove Down Arrow from Combobox, but not Scrollbar?

Tags: wpf

I have a combobox which does not allow text input. Because of this, I don't need the down arrow; just clicking anywhere on the box drops the menu down.

I found this answer: [WPF: ComboBox without dropdown button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373330/wpf-combobox-without-dropdown-button)

However, that answer removes the down arrow AND the resulting scrollbar in the drop down menu. I would like to just remove the down arrow, but not the scrollbar in the drop down menu.

How is this possible?

Comment: Wouldn't a combobox that has text editing disabled *need* to offer the affordance  of a drop down arrow to show that it can be expanded?

Comment: Its obvious in my UI. It doesn't need a drop down arrow. Just clicking anywhere on the combobox brings up the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to edit the control template unfortunately.

This template removes the dropdown arrow (warning; it's super long).  Feel free to customize the template however you like.  I got the original template from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  I Just commented out the lines that show the drop down glyph so that you could see what they originally looked like (Search for "Path" to find them).

```
<Window
    x:Class="comboNoArrow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:comboNoArrow"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>

        <!--  Control colors.  -->
        <Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorLight">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorDark">#FF7381F9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DisabledControlLightColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledControlDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>

        <Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>

        <Color x:Key="ControlLightColor">White</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlMediumColor">#FF7381F9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlDarkColor">#FF211AA9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="ControlMouseOverColor">#FF3843C4</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlPressedColor">#FF211AA9</Color>


        <Color x:Key="GlyphColor">#FF444444</Color>
        <Color x:Key="GlyphMouseOver">sc#1, 0.004391443, 0.002428215, 0.242281124</Color>

        <!--  Border colors  -->
        <Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FF888888</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

        <Color x:Key="PressedBorderLightColor">#FF888888</Color>
        <Color x:Key="PressedBorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderLightColor">#FFAAAAAA</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderDarkColor">#FF888888</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor">Black</Color>

        <!--  Control-specific resources.  -->
        <Color x:Key="HeaderTopColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DatagridCurrentCellBorderColor">Black</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SliderTrackDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="NavButtonFrameColor">#FF3843C4</Color>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuPopupBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
            <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}" />
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#000000FF" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.4" Color="#600000FF" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.6" Color="#600000FF" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#000000FF" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border
                    x:Name="Border"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    CornerRadius="2">
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                    <Border.Background>

                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}" />
                                </GradientStopCollection>
                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>

                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                <Border
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="1"
                    CornerRadius="2,0,0,2">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                <!--<Path
                    x:Name="Arrow"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z">
                    <Path.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource GlyphColor}" />
                    </Path.Fill>
                </Path>-->
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlDarkColor}" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderDarkColor}" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ControlPressedColor}" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Border
                x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                Focusable="False" />
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ToggleButton
                                x:Name="ToggleButton"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                ClickMode="Press"
                                Focusable="false"
                                IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" />
                            <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="ContentSite"
                                Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                            <TextBox
                                x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                Background="Transparent"
                                Focusable="True"
                                IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"
                                Style="{x:Null}"
                                Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
                                Visibility="Hidden" />
                            <Popup
                                x:Name="Popup"
                                AllowsTransparency="True"
                                Focusable="False"
                                IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                                Placement="Bottom"
                                PopupAnimation="Slide">
                                <Grid
                                    x:Name="DropDown"
                                    MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                    MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
                                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EditStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Editable">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentSite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Uneditable" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Border
                            x:Name="Border"
                            Padding="2"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Canvas>
        <ComboBox Width="100" />
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```